# Color a row if column B is not blank and row is even

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to color a row in the case that it is even, and that column B in that row is not blank.

If it was row 1 I would actually need it to be colored in the area A1 to L1 and not the entire row.

Defining a range to color would of course be possible, but I would like a solution that does something like check for the last column that has content in it and then colors all rows from B1 to the last column with content IF column B in the current row is not empty AND the current row is an even number.

My current code colors the rows correctly, but does so with the entire row, as I've used the `.Entirerow`. Is there a genius way to only color until the last used column?

```
Sub farve()

Dim rw As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each rw In rng.Rows
    If rw.row Mod 2 = 0 And Range("B" & rw.row) <> "" Then
        rw.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(Cells(rw.Row, 2), Cells(rw.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)` should do it.

Comment: That works perfectly, but I've just noticed that I need it to always check the column limitation in row 5. Any way to do that? I can see that right now it checks for the row it is currently looping through

Comment: use a variable `c=Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).column` and then use that as the second column parameter in the above.

Comment: I tried entering  5 instead of rw.row in the first one before commenting, but that ended up coloring abseloutely everything in the usedrange, and adding `Dim c As Range` `Set c= Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` ends up getting me a run-time error '424' Object required. `Range(Cells(rw.row, 2), c).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)` is that correct?

Comment: No, `Dim c as Long` because it returns a column numbers, then `c=Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).column` and then inside your loop you would use `Range(Cells(rw.Row, 2), Cells(rw.Row,c)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

Comment: I've added it as an answer as it's getting rather cluttered in the comments.

Comment: I had no idea that you could just write c = , thank you it works perfectly this way. You've been a great help as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments above

```
Sub farve()

Dim rw As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Long

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
c = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each rw In rng.Rows
    If rw.Row Mod 2 = 0 And Range("B" & rw.Row) <> "" Then
         Range(Cells(rw.Row, 2), Cells(rw.Row, c)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it as a conditional formatting rule.

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqewqwew()
    Dim cfrf As String

    cfrf = "=AND(SIGN(LEN($B×ROW×)), NOT(MOD(ROW(×ROW×:×ROW×), 2)))"

    With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
        With .UsedRange.Cells
            'optionally delete pre-existing CFRs
            '.FormatConditions.Delete
            cfrf = Replace(cfrf, "×ROW×", .Cells(1).Row)
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=cfrf)
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .SetFirstPriority
                .StopIfTrue = True
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like the idea of replacing the text in the formula - is that simply to avoid having to close and open brackets in the first line?

Comment: Actually, the OP have given no indication of what his/her data actually looks like and .UsedRange can be horribly unreliable when data does not start in A1 and expand in a contiguous block (like .CurrentRegion) so I thought it best to use .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row in the formula to ensure that the CFR got the rows right. Most likely it could have just been hard-coded as **2**.

Comment: OK, but I was wondering why you defined the string and then did the replacement when you could have done it in one line. (I like your approach though, rather more elegant.)

Comment: There were three instances where the first row number was required. I thought it easier to replace three values in a string rather than concatenate the row number in three times.

Comment: As I thought, will try to remember that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a slightly different approach, define `rng` to only Column B (until last row with Data), and then scan only column B.

```
Option Explicit

Sub farve()

Dim rw As Range
Dim rng As Range

' set the range to column B only, until last cell with data
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each rw In rng.Rows
    If rw.Row Mod 2 = 0 And rw.Value <> "" Then
        rw.Resize(1, Cells(rw.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next rw

End Sub
```